# Error closing main tkinter window with destroy()

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem. I'm trying to close the main window when logging in, with destroy(), but it throws me an error, why? what am I doing wrong? How can I solve it? Any additional information would be appreciated.
The error that I get when I press the button and want to close the window is the following:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/tomassanchezgarcia/Desktop/python-test/iniciar_sesion.py", line 84, in validar
self.root.destroy()
^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Login' object has no attribute 'root'
```

main.py

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import pymysql
from conexion import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from iniciar_sesion import Login

class AplicacionInventario:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("StockMaster")
        self.root.geometry("400x500")
        #Bloquear agrandar ventana
        self.root.resizable(0,0)

        self.wtotal = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.htotal = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
        #  Guardamos el largo y alto de la ventana
        self.wventana = 400
        self.hventana = 500
        # #  Aplicamos la siguiente formula para calcular donde debería posicionarse
        self.pwidth = round(self.wtotal/2-self.wventana/2)
        self.pheight = round(self.htotal/2-self.hventana/2)
        #  Se lo aplicamos a la geometría de la ventana
        self.root.geometry(str(self.wventana)+"x"+str(self.hventana)+"+"+str(self.pwidth)+"+"+str(self.pheight))

        self.imagen = Image.open("src/logo.png")
        self.imagen = self.imagen.resize((350, 100))  # Opcional: Redimensionar la imagen
        self.imagen = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.imagen)
        # Crear un widget Label con la imagen y colocarlo en la ventana
        self.label_imagen = tk.Label(self.root, image=self.imagen)
        self.label_imagen.pack(pady=20)

        self.login1 = Login(self)


        #fetch_data_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Obtener Datos", command=self.mostrar2)
        #fetch_data_button.pack()
        

        self.root.mainloop()

AplicacionInventario()

iniciar_sesion.py

    from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import pymysql
from conexion import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from test2 import Menus

class Login:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

        self.t_Email = "Email:"
        self.label_email = tk.Label(text=self.t_Email)
        self.label_email.pack(pady=5, padx=20)
        self.label_email.place(x=150, y=150, width=100, height=20)
        
        self.entry_email = tk.Entry()
        self.entry_email.pack(pady=5)
        self.entry_email.place(x=75, y=170, width=250, height=50)
        
        self.t_Password = "Contraseña:"
        self.label_password = tk.Label(text=self.t_Password)
        self.label_password.pack(pady=5, padx=20)
        self.label_password.place(x=150, y=220, width=100, height=20)
        
        self.entry_password = tk.Entry(show="*")
        self.entry_password.pack(pady=5)
        self.entry_password.place(x=75, y=240, width=250, height=50)
        
        self.login_email = self.entry_email.get()
        self.login_password = self.entry_password.get()
        
        self.boton_login = tk.Button(text="Iniciar Sesión", command=self.validar)
        self.boton_login.pack(pady=5)
        self.boton_login.place(x=125, y=300, width=150, height=50)

    def validar(self):
        #self.conexion_login = connect_to_database()
        #self.cursor_conexion_login = self.conexion_login.cursor()

        #self.cursor_conexion_login.execute("SELECT email, password FROM usuarios WHERE email=%s AND password=%s", (self.login_email, self.login_password))
        #self.verificar_login = self.cursor_conexion_login.fetchall()

        #messagebox.showwarning("Advertencia", self.verificar_login)

        # Conectarse a la base de datos utilizando la función importada
        self.connection2 = connect_to_database()
        self.cursor2 = self.connection2.cursor()
        # Ejemplo: Ejecutar una consulta para obtener datos
        self.cursor2.execute("SELECT nombre,password FROM usuarios")
        self.data2 = self.cursor2.fetchall()
        #messagebox.showwarning("Advertencia", self.data2)
        # Cerrar el cursor y la conexión
        for self.fila in self.data2:
            self.v_email = self.fila[0]
            self.v_password = self.fila[1]

        self.cursor2.close()
        self.connection2.close()
        if self.entry_email.get() == "" or self.entry_password.get() == "":
            self.dialogo = tk.Toplevel()
            self.dialogo.title("Diálogo Personalizado")
            self.dialogo.geometry("300x50")
            self.dialogo.resizable(0,0)

            self.wtotal2 = self.dialogo.winfo_screenwidth()
            self.htotal2 = self.dialogo.winfo_screenheight()
        
            self.wventana2 = 300
            self.hventana2 = 50
        
            self.pwidth2 = round(self.wtotal2/2-self.wventana2/2)
            self.pheight2 = round(self.htotal2/2-self.hventana2/2)
        
            self.dialogo.geometry(str(self.wventana2)+"x"+str(self.hventana2)+"+"+str(self.pwidth2)+"+"+str(self.pheight2))
            self.etiqueta = tk.Label(self.dialogo, text="Este es un cuadro de diálogo personalizado.", padx=10, pady=10)
            self.etiqueta.pack()
        elif self.entry_email.get() == self.v_email and self.entry_password.get() == self.v_password:
            #messagebox.showwarning("Advertencia", "PERFECTO COINCIDE")
            self.ventana_menu = Menus(self)
        else:
            self.root.destroy()
            messagebox.showwarning("Advertencia", "Los datos introducidos son incorrectos.")
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear, you don't have a `self.root` in your `Login` class. Are you looking for `self.app.root`?

Comment: you are trying to close `root`  which isnt in `Login` class, instead try closing `self.app`.